# Saving hierarchical structur without ChangedTracking

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following DB-Structur:

Manufacturer -> 1:n -> Devices -> 1:n -> Functions

each with some Metadata.

If I want to save my master data, I must insert 63 Manufacturer, 368 Devices and 28789 Functions. This Data comes from an editable File cause not all our customers get all Function etc.

The `DbContext.SaveChanges()` take over 5min. to insert the Data.

I read many Articles where they told to set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false`. But if I do that, only the Manufacturer-Table was stored to DB.

I thought to myself - that's clear, the manufacturer object isn't aware that the Devices-Collection is changed if I disable ChangeTracking.

But how must one use this to get it working?

Comment: Take a look at [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/). As long as EF will emit individual insert statements (as it does by nature) any other optimizations like playing with `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` are futile.

Comment: But they doesn't support nested tables. See the following link: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/discussions/532979